# To create a ggplot2 grids with selected data

Tags: r, ggplot2

[hand drawn Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgiGw.jpg) I would like to create a ggplot using the following 5 variables: District, Site, Year, EpidWeek and Positive.

Code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

ggplot(data = Work_file) + 
  geom_col(mapping = aes(x = Site, y = EpidWeek, fill= "grey")) + 
  geom_col(mapping = aes(x= Positive, y= EpidWeek)) +
  facet_grid(District) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5))+
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,52))
```

My problem is that I want to facet by District, with sites specific to each district in each facet. Instead, I have all the sites from both districts (Multan and Lahore) in each facet. What command should I use?

My sample data is pasted below:

```
Site                           Year        District         EpidWeek    Positive
GULSHAN RAVI STATION, LAHORE    2017         Lahore             1          0
OUTFALL STATION-H, LAHORE       2017         Lahore             2          0
OUTFALL STATION-F, LAHORE       2017         Lahore             2          0
OUTFALL STATION-G, LAHORE       2017         Lahore             2          0
SURAJ MIANI, MULTAN             2017         Multan             2          1
MULTAN ROAD STATION, LAHORE     2017         Lahore             3          0
ALI TOWN, MULTAN                2017         Multan             3          0
KOTLA ABDUL FATAH, MULTAN       2017         Multan             4          0
OUTFALL STATION-G, LAHORE       2017         Lahore             6          0
SURAJ MIANI, MULTAN             2017         Multan             6          0
OUTFALL STATION-H, LAHORE       2017         Lahore             6          0
GULSHAN RAVI STATION, LAHORE    2017         Lahore             6          0
GULSHAN RAVI STATION, LAHORE    2018         Lahore             1          0
OUTFALL STATION-F, LAHORE       2018         Lahore             2          0
SURAJ MIANI, MULTAN             2018         Multan             2          0
OUTFALL STATION-H,LAHORE        2018         Lahore             2          0
OUTFALL STATION-G, LAHORE       2018         Lahore             2          0
MULTAN ROAD STATION, LAHORE     2018         Lahore             3          0
ALI TOWN, MULTAN                2018         Multan             3          0
KOTLA ABDUL FATAH, MULTAN       2018         Multan             5          0
GULSHAN RAVI STATION, LAHORE    2018         Lahore             6          0
SURAJ MIANI, MULTAN             2018         Multan             6          0
OUTFALL STATION-H, LAHORE       2018         Lahore             7          0
OUTFALL STATION-F, LAHORE       2018         Lahore             7          0
```

Comment: Can you post just a few rows of your data with linebreaks for each row?

Comment: how to do line breaks? can u explain plz

Comment: should i do Manually

Comment: Can you cut and paste say five lines from Excel? Press "Shift + Enter" at the end of each row, so that there is a new line

Comment: @RAndStata i tried to edit my post but its still the same can u help me how to convert it into table form?

Comment: alright i will do

Comment: @RAndStata i edited my post. is my table make sense now? or should i edit it more?

Comment: @Z.Lin thank you so much

Comment: @Z.Lin how did you reformat the data? I tried, and it was all over the place.

Comment: @Z.Lin...yes plz share as i will help in future

Comment: @RAndStata Glad it helped. :) You can format a chunk of text / code / data by selecting the whole chunk, and either 1) press the "{ }" button above the text box; or 2) press "Ctrl" + "K" on your keyboard ("Command" + "K" for Mac).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you definitely need to facet_grid(), this will work, and you'll just need to adjust the aspect ratios and sizes:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
        Site = c("GULSHAN RAVI STATION, LAHORE", "OUTFALL STATION-H, LAHORE",
                 "OUTFALL STATION-F, LAHORE", "OUTFALL STATION-G, LAHORE",
                 "SURAJ MIANI, MULTAN", "MULTAN ROAD STATION, LAHORE", "ALI TOWN,
                 MULTAN", "KOTLA ABDUL FATAH, MULTAN", "OUTFALL STATION-G, LAHORE",
                 "SURAJ MIANI, MULTAN", "OUTFALL STATION-H, LAHORE",
                 "GULSHAN RAVI STATION, LAHORE", "GULSHAN RAVI STATION, LAHORE",
                 "OUTFALL STATION-F, LAHORE", "SURAJ MIANI, MULTAN", "OUTFALL STATION-H,
                LAHORE", "OUTFALL STATION-G, LAHORE", "MULTAN ROAD STATION, LAHORE",
                 "ALI TOWN, MULTAN", "KOTLA ABDUL FATAH, MULTAN",
                 "GULSHAN RAVI STATION, LAHORE", "SURAJ MIANI, MULTAN", "OUTFALL STATION-H,
                 LAHORE", "OUTFALL STATION-F, LAHORE"),
        Year = c(2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L,
                 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L,
                 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L),
    District = c("Lahore", "Lahore", "Lahore", "Lahore", "Multan", "Lahore",
                 "Multan", "Multan", "Lahore", "Multan", "Lahore", "Lahore",
                 "Lahore", "Lahore", "Multan", "Lahore", "Lahore", "Lahore",
                 "Multan", "Multan", "Lahore", "Multan", "Lahore", "Lahore"),
    EpidWeek = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 2L,
                 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L),
    Positive = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
                 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)
)


library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

ggplot(data = df) + 
  geom_col(mapping = aes(x = Site, y = EpidWeek, fill= "grey")) + 
  geom_col(mapping = aes(x= Positive, y= EpidWeek)) +
  facet_grid(District ~ Site) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5))+
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,52))
```

[image]

Comment: @RAndStata...i really appreciate your help and time but i am afraid the ggplot feels like have repetition as i have to incorporate other elements in it as well. All i want to have are two grids one "Lahore" and one "Multan" each with respective "Site" and total number of samples collected in each week and positives from respective site.

Comment: @Nido, I have to go for now, but I can try again tomorrow. Can you draw a picture of what sort of graphs you have in mind? I can't picture what you mean

Comment: @RAndStata..ok i will upload the photo. Thank you once again for your kind support

Comment: @Nido actually, I think I might be starting to understand: are you looking for two charts, like the first one that I did, but with not every Site on each one? So only the Sites that are there, and no blanks?

Comment: @RAndStata...I will upload a hand drawn picture soon for reference so that you can have the idea

Comment: @RAndStata...i tried to upload a picture but instead a link code was provided. If you can't see it let me know i will try to share by some other mean.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

The main thing to change in your code is: `facet_wrap(~ District)`

```
df <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
        Site = c("GULSHAN RAVI STATION, LAHORE", "OUTFALL STATION-H, LAHORE",
                 "OUTFALL STATION-F, LAHORE", "OUTFALL STATION-G, LAHORE",
                 "SURAJ MIANI, MULTAN", "MULTAN ROAD STATION, LAHORE", "ALI TOWN,
                 MULTAN", "KOTLA ABDUL FATAH, MULTAN", "OUTFALL STATION-G, LAHORE",
                 "SURAJ MIANI, MULTAN", "OUTFALL STATION-H, LAHORE",
                 "GULSHAN RAVI STATION, LAHORE", "GULSHAN RAVI STATION, LAHORE",
                 "OUTFALL STATION-F, LAHORE", "SURAJ MIANI, MULTAN", "OUTFALL STATION-H,
                LAHORE", "OUTFALL STATION-G, LAHORE", "MULTAN ROAD STATION, LAHORE",
                 "ALI TOWN, MULTAN", "KOTLA ABDUL FATAH, MULTAN",
                 "GULSHAN RAVI STATION, LAHORE", "SURAJ MIANI, MULTAN", "OUTFALL STATION-H,
                 LAHORE", "OUTFALL STATION-F, LAHORE"),
        Year = c(2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L,
                 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L,
                 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L),
    District = c("Lahore", "Lahore", "Lahore", "Lahore", "Multan", "Lahore",
                 "Multan", "Multan", "Lahore", "Multan", "Lahore", "Lahore",
                 "Lahore", "Lahore", "Multan", "Lahore", "Lahore", "Lahore",
                 "Multan", "Multan", "Lahore", "Multan", "Lahore", "Lahore"),
    EpidWeek = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 2L,
                 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L),
    Positive = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
                 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)
)


library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

ggplot(data = df) + 
  geom_col(mapping = aes(x = Site, y = EpidWeek, fill= "grey")) + 
  geom_col(mapping = aes(x= Positive, y= EpidWeek)) +
  facet_wrap( ~ District) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5))+
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,52))
```

Gives you output like:

[image]

Comment: @RAndStata...thank you for your kind help. i have a concern, i just posted a little portion of my data. As it is quite long, then i am afraid the whole df exercise will consume a lot of time. is there any shortcut?

Comment: You can just use this code on your full file, it should work. Let me know if it doesn't.  


`ggplot(data = Work_file) + 
  geom_col(mapping = aes(x = Site, y = EpidWeek, fill= "grey")) + 
  geom_col(mapping = aes(x= Positive, y= EpidWeek)) +
  facet_wrap( ~ District) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5))+
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,52))`

Comment: @RAndStata....Yes i had similar ggplot output. as you can see in the ggplot that i have two districts "Lahore" and "Multan" and in Lahore there are 5 "sites" and in Multan there are 3 sites. i want to have a facet grid of two districts with their respective sites separately.

Comment: So just ignore the part where I put in the data, and just use the part below. And you'll need to change back the `ggplot(data = Work_file)`

Comment: @Nido okay, let me try

Comment: @RAndStata...my problem is still there i want to separate sites i.e. in each district facet grid i want to have only its respective "site"

Comment: @RAndStata...i tried to upload a picture but instead a link code was provided. If you can't see it let me know i will try to share by some other mean.

Comment: @Nido Sorry, I can't see your digram at all

Comment: @RAndStata...i uploaded it but cant embed it. but if you can see my post from start there is a link name "Hand drawn diagram" can u click on that to see the picture?

Comment: @Nido thanks. I don't have an answer for you right now, but it looks like you might be trying to do a "grouped barplot" within the facets? If so, that's `+ geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")` and you change `fill = ` in `ggplot()`

Comment: @RAndStata...thank you so much for your kind help and precious time if you find any solution do share will really appreciate